# Google Earth .kmz files are opened with Adobe Photoshop on OSx Mavericks

Tags: macos, adobe-photoshop, google-earth

I frequently get GE placemarks as email attachments. Whenever I click on a Google Earth `.kmz` placemark my Adobe Photoshop CC launches. I can't find anyplace in PS preferences to block auto launching. Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Using Finder, locate a .kmz file on your system.

Ctrl-click on the file and select **Get Info** from the context menu.

Locate the section in the Info panel that appears titled: `Open with:`

Select the application you would like to handle files with that extension (.kmz in this case).  If you don't see your application listed, there is an `Other...` choice at the bottom that will allow you to find the application via browsing in a Finder-like interface.

Then click the button just below that titled: `Change All...` and then click `Continue` when prompted with "Are you sure... blah, blah, blah."

All your `.kmz` files should now open with the application you chose.  If that was Google Earth, you'll likely be happy at this point.

Comment: @Brad - I'm very glad that it solved your issue!  You may feel free to thank me also by up-voting my answer and/or marking it as the 'accepted' answer.  Thanks & welcome to superuser!!

Answer (score -2):

On my pc, whichever program was intalled last is the one that will open the kmz files. CS5 was opening my KMZs because i installed it after Google Earth. So, I uninstalled GE and then reinstalled it. Since then, no problems at all. The KMZs open launch Google Earth every time!